# Function not producing intended results?

Tags: python, function, trigonometry

I am having some trouble trying to figure out why one of my functions isn't producing the results I expect. I am pretty sure it has something to do with converting this equation into code but I can't pinpoint what is wrong exactly.

This is the given formula: 
[d=radius * arccos(sin(x1)sin(x2)+cos(x1)cos(x2)cos(|y1-y2|)) http://img42.com/yfTmc+](http://img42.com/yfTmc+)

Here is my code:

```
part1 = math.cos(abs(y1 - y2))
part2 = math.cos(x1) * math.cos(x2)
part3 = math.sin(x1) * math.sin(x2)
d = RADIUS * math.acos(part3 + (part2 * part1))
return d
```

Comment: Without knowing what the intended and the actual results are, it's a little hard to say what's wrong.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to this part of the code. I believe it is an issue with translating the equation into the function. I can't seem to figure out what part is wrong though.

Comment: But *what* is the output supposed to be and what is it outputting now? What are `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, and `y2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving your values in degrees instead of the radians that the `math.sin`, etc. functions expect. Try converting your values to radians with `math.radians(degValue)`.